# How to check is there any session in Yii2 without write check session it in each page?

Tags: php, session, yii2

I have an application using **Yii2** framework, steps for using apps:

1. Access *localhost/college/web/login*
2. Login using username and password
3. Select month (in here user select month, and then the selected month will be set into *session*) and click submit

then application will show the data base on selected month, and in controller, I use the session of selected month for filtering data.

In here, I have an issue, that if user access application through url *localhost/college/web/student/index* and etc (except *localhost/college/web/login*), the apps will redirect into login page, and after enter the login credential the apps will redirect the user into page *localhost/college/web/student/index*, and then the page will show error page. Because there is no session of selected month.

How do I can set if there is no session then redirect to login page without write `if(!isset(session'selected-month'){ render 'login'; })` in each page?

Comment: How do you set this month in session?

Comment: Could you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

I think it may help you [Yii RBAC](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-authorization) create your own base controller and overwinter behaviors function according to your need.

```
[
    'class' => AccessControl::className(),
    ...
    'denyCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
        throw new \Exception('You are not allowed to access this page');
    }
]
```